# Multiple input value in array with checkbox selection

Tags: php, arrays

I have created a form (with php & MySQL) where users will select some records with checkbox and submit them, which will update those records in DB. I have used the variable recordid[]. That works fine. But now I need to use another variable (arddressid, which is a mandatory field of every record) for each record selected, as hidden field. I need that data for updating some other tables.

The issue is I am not able to echo the recordid and corresponding addressid together. I know my 'foreach' statement is not correct, but I cant fix this.

Any help will be appreciated.

The php file with checkboxes is as follows:

```
<tbody>    
    <?php 
    $sql_select = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM tblapprovedrenewal 
    WHERE renewalstatus = 0 AND status = 1 ORDER BY subscriptionexpiry, inserttimestamp");
    if(mysqli_num_rows($sql_select) > 0){ 
    while ($result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql_select)){ ?>                
    <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="checkitem" name="recordid[]" value="<?php echo $result['recordid']; ?>"></td>
    <input type="hidden" name="addressid[]" value="<?php echo $result['addressid']; ?>">
    <td><?php echo $result['name']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $result['address']; ?></td>                    
    <td><?php echo $result['subscriptionexpiry']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $result['inserttimestamp']; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php } 
    } ?>
    </tbody>
```

The php file echoing the result has the following lines of codes:

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['disapprove'])){
 if(!empty($_POST['recordid'])){
 foreach($_POST['recordid'] as $value => $recordid) {
//          foreach($_POST['recordid'] as $recordid ) {

  echo $recordid. ': '. $_POST['addressid'][$value].'</br>';
  }
 }
}
?>
```

The result shows:

[image]

It displays the recordid correctly, but the address id is not correct.

All I want is to show the recordid and the corresponding addressid.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can anyone please help me with this? Any alternate way of achieving the same result will also be helpful, so that I can change my codes accordingly. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$recordIdList = $_POST['recordid'];
$addressIdList = $_POST['addressid'];
if(isset($_POST['disapprove'])){
    if(!empty($recordIdList)){
        foreach ($recordIdList as $index => $recordId) {
            $addressId = $addressIdList[$index];
            echo "{$recordId}: {$addressId}<br />";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer is almost similar to what I tried and generates the same result, which unfortunately is incorrect. Thanks for your effort. anyway.